# Accounts UI {{> loginButtons}} now showing on ios device. No Dom children after first container

Tags: ios, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have ran into a situation with accounts ui unstyled while testing on an ios device. Everything works fine in the app and on the simulator. On the ios device the #login-buttons container is empty where additional dom nodes should be.

The attached screen shot will show what I mean.

Current packages install:
Accounts Ui unstyled
Gmaps
FlowRouter
mdg Camera

[image]

I recently ditched Facebook login from the user accounts package because it was not working properly. I am disappointed to see this is also having issues at the device level as well.

I have tried with the regular accounts ui (regular) instead of accounts ui unstyled and moving it outside FlowRouter to make sure it wasn't a conflict with those.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device wifi is on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the wifi network was correct, **the problem was the firewall.** Opening the port 3000 solved the problem ..

So, disable Firewall or open port 3000